# Powershell vs UNIX

Tags: unix, powershell

I would like to know if there is any equivalent Powershell commands for the following
UNIX commands:

1. make
2. trap

Comment: Does this question have something to do with 4chan?

Comment: `make` is not a shell command. You can launch the program `make` from any shell you wish as long as it is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has [nmake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha%28VS.71%29.aspx) available, but I would recommend installing [GNU Make](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) from GNUWin32.  Note both are just programs, not built-ins.

Powershell has its own variant of [trap](http://huddledmasses.org/trap-exception-in-powershell/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply.
Is there any cmdlet in Powershell which has similar functionality like make? I would like to write a Powershell script which can build some packages.

Comment: @shivashis - No there isn't anything built-in.  However take a look at the PSake project if you're interested in make-like functionality (http://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake).

Comment: I was reading about Powershell Trap and found we can trap different errors and exceptions, e.g. divide by zero, etc. How can we trap signals, e.g Ctrl + C or SIGHUP, etc? Is there an equivalent thing in powershell or these are UNIX specific only? Thanks

Comment: The standalone script [Invoke-Build.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build). Its concepts are similar to *MSBuild* but build scripts are written in PowerShell and look like mentioned *psake* scripts (but not compatible).